# How to filter and load video comments

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am not good at English, so please understand that I am writing through a translator.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list

I am trying to retrieve spam comments and delete them through this API.

There is a parameter called "searchTerms", so I think I can use it, but the problem is that there are spam comments.

For example, if you try to search for the comment “Hello”

"H+++e$$l^^^lo\\\"
,"H$%#%#$e^%$ll^%^o"

It has been set up so that it cannot be viewed in this format. If I could use regular expressions, it would be easy to retrieve spam comments like that. I wonder if there is a way to use regular expressions or a way to retrieve spam comments like that effectively.

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible, I recommend you to list all comments and then locally filter as you want.

Comment: YouTube studio already has an inbuilt system for flagging spam comments why not just let it do it